# jQuery event listening on child elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is this expected behaviour of jQuery's `trigger` and `on`?

Given a form inside a div, if the form is told to trigger a custom `done` event, the div container can listen to it... That seems very wrong.

https://jsfiddle.net/oyw1Lzxs/

```
$('form').on('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).trigger('done', {
    ok: 1
  })
})

$('#hi').on('done', function(e, data) {
  console.log(data) // {ok:1}
})
```

Comment: This is the event bubbling up through the dom.  It is important and necessary, especially for things like click or hover events where sometimes the only place you can catch them is the parent of the triggering element.  If you want to prevent this behavior, you can call e.stopPropagation(); and the event will end there (when/wherever you call it).

Comment: @Wrinn It's on submit here, so it's fine

Comment: If you don't want your custom event to bubble up in the DOM tree, use `stopPropagation` ([docs](https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/)) in the event handler.